# Loop space directory name

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

I have a `CT.txt` with below input data.
CT.txt:

```
test testing test 1
```

And with below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for CITY in $(cat /home/user/CT.txt)
do
 FILES=/mnt/dir1/dir2/$CITY/*
echo $FILES
```

Giving me output as follow:

```
/mnt/dir1/dir2/test
/mnt/dir1/dir2/testing
/mnt/dir1/dir2/test/*
/mnt/dir1/dir2/1/*
```

where output should be:

```
/mnt/dir1/dir2/test
/mnt/dir1/dir2/testing
/mnt/dir1/dir2/test 1
```

How to make `CT.txt` file to read having space in between **test 1**.

Comment: if your `CT.txt` content is linear you cannot even achieve it by quoting. Is your `CT.txt` content are in one line only?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the FS (field seperator) in awk you could achieve it.

```
awk -F: '{ print "/mnt/dir1/dir2/"$1 }' CT.txt
```

Comment: The `CT.txt` there is no field seperator `:`! also all contents are in one line but you just reading one, even if it was space or tab, we don't know `test 1` is filename or `test` and `1` are seperate files

Comment: Yes, if all is in one line, it wouldn't work, but if each line is an entry, than we could achieve it with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CT.txt has entries one / line, then the `while` loop is better suited to your task:

```
while IFS= read -r CITY; do
   FILES=/mnt/dir1/dir2/$CITY
   echo "$FILES"/*
done < /home/user/CT.txt
```

The `for` loop is ill-suited for this, however, it can still be made to work:

```
# set the input field separator to newline and disable globbing
IFS=$'\n';set -f
for CITY in $(< /home/user/CT.txt); do
   FILES=/mnt/dir1/dir2/$CITY
   echo "$FILES"/*
done
```